# Read WLAN Link Layer packages using tcpdump/tshark in raspberry pi

Tags: linux, tcpdump, wifi, tshark, data-link-layer

I have a raspberry pi, a WLAN stick (Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370) in monitor mode and tcpdump (+tshark) installed.

Now I want to read link layer packages from a WLAN wristband device that patients in a retirement home use. This device sends link layer data every second in order to be detected by access points using fingerprinting. The content of this packages is not important, only the RSSI values and the MAC of the device is needed.

With my rPi now I wants to detect when a patient is neat to its own flat door in order to open it automatically. For this, the Pi needs to receives this LLC packages so that I can use the associated RSSI value to calculate the distance.

Using Wireshark and Windows (Airpcap) I can read these LLC packages without problems. The output is for example:

35748   152.953461000   00:00:00_00:00:00   57:01:ff:00:00:00   LLC 62  I, N(R)=0, N(S)=0; DSAP NULL LSAP Individual, SSAP 0x1e Command

If I do the same thing on raspbian using tcpdump or tshark, I don't receive data at all.

tcpdump (command is sudo tcpdump llc -i wlan1) returns

tcpdump: 'llc' supported only on raw ATM

Looks like my linux/driver is not able to pass link layer data to tcpdump. How can I enable it?

Thank you for any hint

## UPDATE

Thanks to Guy Harris I found a solution

```
sudo tcpdump -e -i wlan1 type data
```

returns all LLC packages and the -e value adds all types of mac. Output is something like this where TA is the MAC of the device. I parsed it using python line by line to get the data I needed

```
02:56:21.346146 11.0 Mb/s 2462 MHz 11b -53dB signal antenna 1 RA:01:40:96:00:00:03 (oui Unknown) TA:00:18:8e:40:62:03 (oui Unknown) DA:00:00:00:00:00:00 (oui Ethernet) SA:00:00:00:00:00:00 (oui Ethernet) LLC, dsap Null (0x00) Individual, ssap OSI (0xfe) Response, ctrl 0x0b: Unnumbered, 0b, Flags [Response], length 24
```

BR
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tcpdump: 'llc' supported only on raw ATM

First of all, the filter comes *after* all the command-line flags, including `-i`, so, if you're going to be capturing on wlan1 with a filter, what you want is

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlan1 {filter}
```

That's how tcpdump works - the filter comes *after* all the command-line flags and the arguments to those flags, including `-i`, `-r`, etc.

Second of all, "llc" means something very specific - from the "pcap-filter" man page (with older versions of libpcap and tcpdump, it's in the tcpdump man page, but the filter expressions aren't understood by tcpdump, they're understood by libpcap, the library tcpdump uses to capture and to read capture files):

```
   llc    True if the packet is an ATM packet, for SunATM on Solaris,  and
          is an LLC-encapsulated packet.
```

On 802.11, all 802.11 data frames have an 802.2 LLC header, so you want

```
tcpdump -i wlan1 type data
```

which will filter out management and control frames (which don't have 802.2 LLC headers).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your feedback. But the result is the same even if I use your command

Comment: "But the result is the same even if I use your command"  I.e., it prints "tcpdump: 'llc' supported only on raw ATM"?

Comment: I don't see any output there.

Comment: sorry, I was to fast=)  

pi@proPi2 ~ $ sudo tcpdump -i wlan1 llc  

tcpdump: 'llc' supported only on raw ATM

Comment: OK, so what does `tcpdump -i wlan1 -L` print?

Comment: Data link types for wlan1 when not in monitor mode (use option -y to set):
  IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header)

Comment: OK, so if you just capture on wlan1 you're *NOT* capturing in monitor mode.

Comment: Or, at least, tcpdump thinks so, because there's no way for libpcap to tell it otherwise.  It *should* support "llc" with DLT_ IEEE802_11_RADIO; what does `tcpdump -h` print?

Comment: tcpdump version 4.3.0;
libpcap version 1.3.0;

Comment: the card should be in monitor mode, at least iwconfig says so: wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

Comment: No, it *shouldn't* support llc - that's specific to ATM.  See the updated answer.

Comment: thank you Guy! Works very smooth if I save it to a pcap and check it in wireshark filtering by "frame contains 00:18:8e:*" A last question: I want to read these data in real time whitout parsing the result in whireshark. If I find a LLC package that has transmitter address 00:18:8e:*, then I want to print its tramsmitter address and the RSSI value on the console. Do you also have a hint here? Thank you =)

Comment: "then I want to print its tramsmitter address" See [IEEE Std 802.11-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2012.pdf).  "and the RSSI value" See [the radiotap specification](http://www.radiotap.org) and the [antenna signal](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Antenna%20signal) and [the dB antenna signal](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/dB%20antenna%20signal) fields.

Comment: Or run tcpdump and parse its output, or run TShark and use `-T fields` and the appropriate `-e` flags to print the relevant fields (although note that TShark uses a temporary file for the capture, which you might not want).

Comment: thank you, I used -e in tcpdump and parsed the output line by line in python. Works good